# Hide navbar in mobile browsers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, uinavigationbar

I'm making a mobile responsive site using Twitter Bootstrap. I'd like to completely hide the top navbar when the site is viewed on mobile. Anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the responsive utility classes `.hidden-phone` and `.hidden-tablet`

```
<div class="navbar hidden-tablet hidden-phone">
```

You could also use a media query such as..

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .navbar{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

More on responsive classes here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

### [Demo](http://bootply.com/61803)

Answer (score 1):

[Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) has just `.hidden-xs/sm/md/lg`

Phone/tablet/desktop apply for BS2.x only

Answer (score 0):

Try this!
just add "hidden-xs" to the div class

```
<div class="navbar hidden-xs">
```